# facing error in django admin inline with djongo db connector

Tags: django, djongo

I'm using the `ArrayReferenceField` instead of `ManyToManyField` because I'm using `djongo` as my database connector. I want this field to be shown as inline model in the django admin site. But I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'ArrayReferenceDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'`. I know that `ArrayReferenceField` does not create an intermediate model in the database. So how can I successfully show this field as inline in the django admin?

My models:

```
class Synonym(models.Model):
    base_name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=5000,
        verbose_name='Base Entity Value',
        help_text='The entity value for which you want to provide the synonym.',
    )

    extra_name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=5000,
        verbose_name='A synonym',
        help_text='Synonyms of the base entity value.',
    )

    class Meta:
        # abstract = True
        ordering = ['base_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base_name

class qa(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    synonyms = models.ArrayReferenceField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        to=Synonym,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text='Synonyms of the entities of the question.',
    )
```

In admin.py:

```
class SynonymInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = qa.synonyms.through


class SynonymAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SynonymInline,
    ]


@admin.register(qa)
class qaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # form = qaModelForm

    list_display = ('question', 'answer', 'module', 'intent', 'display_entities_name')

    list_filter = ('module', 'intent', 'username',)

    inlines = [
        SynonymInline,
    ]
```